# How to do a 3 stage Map Reduce streaming?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am very new to hadoop.

Currently I have a mapper and a reducer and a combiner.
And I could do `cat file | mapper.py | reducer.py | combiner.py` to produce the result. And the reducing stage is embarrassingly parallisable. So, could anyone tell me how to do fit it into hadoop streaming given that I have a hadoop cluster?

Comment: `reducer` and `combiner` code is same if the operation is commutative and associative in the reducer. you can refer [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/a-guide-to-python-frameworks-for-hadoop/)

Answer (score 1):

hadoop streaming supports stdin/stdout.  So you can reuse your mapper.py, reducer.py, and combiner.py

Consider the signature:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper \
    -reducer org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer \
    -D stream.map.output.field.separator=. \
    -D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=4
```

So you can use this signature to achieve the first two steps i.e. mapper.py and reducer.py.

```
--mapper  mapper.py  --reducer reducer.py
```

Then you can make the combiner by adding another hadoop streaming with just a reducer step

```
  <first part> |  --  reducer 'combiner.py'
```

Comment: Does it means treat `hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar ` with mapper and reducer as a new mapper?

Comment: @darwinsenior  I did not say that the reducer is a new mapper. I said the mapper.py and reducer.py are the mapper and reducer of the first submitted job.    The combiner is the reducer of the second submitted job - it is chained to run after the first job is completed.